# Getting inflateException at layout inside aar library file

Tags: java, android, aar, lib

I converted my project into library having included some java, layout, string, resources and menifest file. Now i want to use that aar file in another project. After export when i am trying to call activity from aar library I am getting error of Binary XML file line #: Error inflating class.
I used MovableFloatingActionButton custom class and created button in layout inside aar library only.

**errors are like**

```
> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #86:
> Error inflating class com.***.****.MovableFloatingActionButton
> 
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> com.***.****.MovableFloatingActionButton
> 
> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
> Lcom/google/android/material/floatingactionbutton/FloatingActionButton;
> 
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
> "com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton"
> on path: DexPathList[[zip file
> "/data/app/com.***.****-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.*****.****-1/lib/arm64,
> /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that the classloader didnt find class for to inflate complex view which that class is instantiaded in.
The possible problems are:

-1- If Your proguard is enabled, try to disable it, and test if the view or layout is inflated. If it works, You need to configure proguard files for.

-2- Doublecheck typo mistake and package for inflated class, by clicking on its last part, the simple class name in layout xml file, in you case it should be com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.**FloatingActionbutton**, (hold CTRL key on keyboard and click to bordered part of xml tag) if it opens source file, than it is ok, otherwise class really does not exists and you need to write right class path to instantiate it.

-3- If You are using multidex, or You want to support pre-art devices, which still use dex and not art (mainly pre-lollipop device) then does not forget to override Application class and use MultidexApplication or include the attachBaseContext() to have the Multidex.install(this) inside body.
And do not forget to put the correct path of this class inside your manifest application tag.

example:

```
class MyApplication : Application() {
    /**
     * multidex support, do not remove to backward compatibility before ART (DEX need it)
     * */
    override fun attachBaseContext(base: Context?) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base)

        MultiDex.install(this)
    }
    ...
}
```

and:

```
<application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true" ... >
```

One of this should solve Your problem.

Comment: That is working fine as a application. But when I am creating aar file and using in another project either using libs folder or import aar module. its giving me those errors. Ideally if application is working fine then aar has to be too. But might I am missing something so aar not working.

Comment: Your aar file is with proguard enabled?

Comment: Unsure then, need more build information and library project configuration detail. Can you post build.gradle for instance?